# Formulario de login/registro con Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario de login y uno de registro y el problema esta con el email. Si yo en las reglas de validación no agrego el tipo email:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
```

y sin querer registro un email con espacios al principio o al final lo registra: por ej: "  miemail@laravel.com  ", dando error después al momento de loguearse.

Ahora, si le agrego el tipo email:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
```

y quiero registrar y sin querer agrego un espacio, me dice que el email ingresado no es válido.

En mi opinión, no tendría que permitirse agregar con espacios al principio o final, y luego quitarse al momento del registro?

Comment: no, los emails no pueden contener espacios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese problema lo solucionó Laravel en su versión 5.4 con el middleware TrimStrings, simplemente basta con agregarlo a `App/Kernel.php` para que elimine los espacios antes y después de las "strings" de los request, como el correo en este caso.

Agrega la siguiente línea al archivo en mención:

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
```

El código de este middleware es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware;

class TrimStrings extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->except, true)) {
            return $value;
        }
        return is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;
    }
}
```